# sort is equal to inversions logic

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, big-o-notation

In Bubble sort, the number of swaps/comparisons is equal to the number of inversions.

1st pass it will do (n -1) comparison 
2nd pass it will do (n-2) comparison....so on 
(n-1)n = n^2 - n
Worst case of bubble sort is theta(n^2)

How is the number of inversions theta(n^2) too??
please explain the logic behind this

Comment: "In Bubble sort, the number of swaps/comparisons is equal to the number of inversions": does this reflect your opinion ? Otherwise, tell us the reference. [The statement is wrong.]

Answer (score 0):

At every "phase" it will do that much comparisons. Since there are $n$ such "phases", the number of comparisons can be worst case $\Theta(n^2)$

Comment: so that means in an array with elements say {1,2,3,4,5} the number of inversions will be Θ(n)?

Comment: In this specific array, no. But in the array $[5,4,3,2,1]$ - it will be $\Theta(n)$ at every phase of bubblesort

Answer (score 0):

The number of swaps and the number of comparisons are two different measures.

The number of swaps in BubbleSort is always equal to the number of inversions in the original array. To see this, it suffices to notice that each swap decreases the number of inversions by exactly $1$ and that a sorted array has $0$ inversions.

The number of comparisons is only weakly related to the number of inversions. To see this, notice that BubbleSort performs $n-1$ comparison on a sorted array (which has no inversions).
Moreover, even if the input array is not sorted BubbleSort can perform $\Omega(n \cdot i)$ comparisons when there are just $O(i)$ inversions.
To see this assume $i \le \frac{n}{2}$ and consider an input array consisting of two consecutive sorted blocks of elements. The first blocks contains the integers from $i+1$ to $n$, and the second block contains the integers from $1$ to $i$.  BubbleSort needs $\Omega(n)$ iterations, and hence $\Omega(n^2)$ comparisons, while the number of inversions is $i \cdot (n-i) = O(n \cdot i)$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of inversions in an array does not depend on any algorithm. It ranges from $0$ (sorted sequence) to $\dfrac{(n-1)n}2$ (reverse sorted sequence), so is $O(n^2)$ and  but not $\Theta(n^2)$.

It turns out that bubble sort performs exactly that number of swaps.

The "blind" version that you evaluated performs exactly $\dfrac{(n-1)n}2$ comparisons in all cases, and that is $\Theta(n^2)$.

A variant will stop a pass at the last swap performed at the previous pass, possibly reducing to $n-1=O(n)$ comparisons in total, which is the minimum possible !